# $k$th term of Taylor series of function $f(x) = 3x^3-2x+4$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm having trouble solving this question. I have all the values right but can't figure out a way to find the $k$th term. My Taylor series values up to that point are $4,\frac{-2}{1!},\frac{0x^2}{2!},\frac{18x^3}{3!}$ so what would the $k$th term be?

Comment: To put it loosely, the point of a Taylor series is to convert a general function into a polynomial.  You've already got a polynomial, so it is its own Taylor series. You've properly identified the first four terms of it; anything thereafter must be $0\cdot x^k/k!$.

Comment: Is the problem actually asking for the Taylor series of a finite polynomial?  Notice that you've already found the four terms of your polynomial expressed as Taylor terms.  Is there anything else left?  What then are the other terms in general?

Comment: that's what im asking, I guess I worded it poorly. I need to know what in general the other polynomials would be.

Comment: Do you see how to apply my answer to your example?

Comment: not really, im pretty lost with it.

Comment: @Joe: See my expanded answer, and if you get stuck again, let me know what's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're looking at the Taylor series about $x=0$. This is simplicity in itself for polynomials in standard form $$p(x)=a_nx^n+\cdots+a_0$$ where the $a_j$ are real and $a_n\neq0$. In particular, the $k$th term of the Taylor series of $p(x)$ about $x=0$ will be $a_kx^k$ for $0\le k\le n$ and will be $0$ for $k>n.$ This is because $p^{(k)}(x)$ is identically zero for $k>n,$ and because $p^{(k)}(0)=k!a_k$ for $0\le k\le n$.

Let's prove this, shall we? To facilitate things, I will rewrite the polynomial as $$p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^na_jx^j.$$ You should be able to show that for any integers $j,k\ge 0$, we have $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[x^j]=\begin{cases}x^j & k=0\\(j)_kx^{j-k} & 0<k<j\\j! & k=j\\0 & k>j,\end{cases}\tag{$\clubsuit$}$$ where $(j)_k$ indicates the [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol). Now, $$\begin{align}p^{(k)}(x) &= \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[\sum_{j=0}^na_jx^j\right]\\ &= \sum_{j=0}^na_j\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[x^j],\end{align},$$ so it follows by $(\clubsuit)$ that $p^{(k)}(x)$ is identically zero for $k>n$. We also see by $(\clubsuit)$ that $$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}[x^j]\Biggr|_{x=0}=\begin{cases}0 & k\neq j\\k! & j=k,\end{cases}$$ so $$p^{(k)}(0)=a_kk!$$ for $0\le k\le n$. Since the $k$th term of our Taylor series about $x=0$ is $$\frac{p^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k,$$ then the $k$th term is $a_kx^k$ for $0\le k\le n$ and $0$ for $k>n$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

As Cameron already presented, the answer is : for $k> n$ the terms are equal to $0$. The reason is easily found in the Taylor series expression. For a function $f(x)$ , the TS is :
\begin{equation}
\sum \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k
\end{equation}
where $f^{(k)}$ is the k-th derivative of the function $f(x)$

In your case, $f(x)$ is your polynomial of degree $n=3$.
So, the coefficient for the forth term $\frac{f^{(4)}(a)}{4!}=\frac{0}{4!}=0$. You will get $0$ for all of the terms of order higher than $n$ because when $k> n$ the derivative $f^{(k)}(a)$ will be zero which will make the entire coefficient zero.

The reason why the forth derivative $f^{(4)}(a)=0$ is because the third derivative is equal to 18.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, the kth term of the Taylor polynomial of $P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ... + a_n x^n$ will be the monomial with the $k-1$ degree.  So for example, in your polynomial when $k=4$, the term will be $a_3 x^3 \text {which is} 3x^3$.

So if $k > n$, the Taylor coefficient is equal to zero, so the Taylor expansion of a finite degree polynomial ends up looking like the original polynomial itself.